# Calculate Avg Time in R

Tags: r, time, hour, minute

My `Dataframe` called `copy1`:

```
    copy1
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: GM [2]

      GM Avg.Start.Time Avg.Close.Time Avg.Last.Task.Duration
  (fctr)         (fctr)         (fctr)                  (int)
1   ED          13:15          16:16                    181
2   ED          16:12          17:44                     92
3   LD          15:32          17:27                    115
4   LD          14:38          17:11                    153
```

I want to calculate `Avg.Close.Time` Per `GM`

I have tried:

```
copy1$Avg.Start.Time <-strptime(copy1$Avg.Start.Time, "%H:%M")
copy1%>%group_by(GM)%>%
        summarise(mean(copy1$Avg.Start.Time,na.rm=T))
```

But get this:

```
Error: column 'Avg.Start.Time' has unsupported type : POSIXlt, POSIXt
```

I have also tried using `lubridate`:

```
copy1$Avg.Start.Time <- hm(copy1$Avg.Start.Time)

mean(copy1$Avg.Start.Time,na.rm = T)
```

But get "0"

Any ideas how can I calculate `Avg.Start.Time` Per `GM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as.POSIXct` to do the conversion, the result of which can be used for `mean`:

```
result <- copy1%>%group_by(GM)%>%
  summarise(mean(as.POSIXct(Avg.Start.Time, format="%M:%S"),na.rm=T))
```

However, this will add the current date to the time:

```
print(result)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
##      GM mean(as.POSIXct(copy1$Avg.Start.Time,...
##  <fctr>                                   <time>
##1     ED                      2016-08-24 00:14:54
##2     LD                      2016-08-24 00:15:05
```

---

As pointed out by the OP, we can `format` the result to remove the date:

```
result <- copy1%>%group_by(GM)%>%
  summarise(Avg.Start.Time=format(mean(as.POSIXct(Avg.Start.Time, format="%M:%S"),na.rm=T), format="%M:%S"))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
##      GM Avg.Start.Time
##  <fctr>          <chr>
##1     ED          14:43
##2     LD          15:05
```

Comment: thanks for it is not a valid answer. both times are returned the same

Comment: @Shery: sorry, just a typo using `copy1$Avg.Start.Time` in `summarise` instead of just `Avg.Start.Time`. In any case, the other answer is much better since it strips the date.

Comment: you can format the time using `format(format = "%H:%M")` at the end as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to first convert the column to time format by,

```
copy1$Avg.Start.Time <- as.POSIXct(copy1$Avg.Start.Time, format = "%H:%M")
```

You can then use `aggregate` from base R to get `mean` for every `GM`

```
aggregate(Avg.Start.Time~GM, copy1, mean)

#  GM      Avg.Start.Time
#1 ED 2016-08-24 14:43:30
#2 LD 2016-08-24 15:05:00
```

If you want it in `HH:MM` format you can wrap it up inside `format`

```
aggregate(Avg.Start.Time~GM, copy1, function(x) format(mean(x),format = "%H:%M"))

#  GM Avg.Start.Time
#1 ED          14:43
#2 LD          15:05
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(copy1)[,.(Avg.Start.Time = mean(as.POSIXct(Avg.Start.Time, format = "%M:%S")))  , GM]
```